# array index 2 is past the end of the array

Tags: c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

The string array d[2] should have 3 elements. But it seems that it can contain only 2 elements. The 3rd element is not being stored in the array. What is the reason? Does it have to do anyting with the memory allocation which I have done with the **new** operator?

```
#include<iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {   
        std::string d[2];
        d[0] = "Dilshdur";
        d[1] = "Dilshad";
        d[2] = "Dolon";
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            std::cout<<d[i]<<std::endl;
        }

    }


};


int main()
{
   A *p;
   p = new A;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's seems to be something you missed when  reading or learning about arrays, because the size you provide when defining the array is the number of elements, not the top index.

So

```
std::string d[2];
```

will define `d` as an array of ***two*** elements, with the indexes `0` and `1`.

---

If you don't know the number of elements beforehand, then use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as it will allow you to add elements dynamically at run-time.

Comment: I don't know why I missed this obvious thing. Thanks.